# Laravel - Unexpected behavior in BelongsTo relationship after model creation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm having a weird behavior in a BelongsTo relationship after a model creation.

I'm creating and address and associating a country to it, to achieve that, I'm using the create method of the address model, this is the snippet of code:

```
$country = Country::find($input['country']);
$user = User::find($input['user']);

$address = Address::create($input);       // Address created and saved
$address->user()->associate($user);       // Works perfectly
$address->country()->associate($country); // Does not work :(
$address->push();
```

After that, I'm having this error in the line where the country-address association is done:

```
ErrorException in BelongsTo.php line 75:
Undefined property: App\Models\Address::$country
```

The weird behavior is that the address-user association is working, and the association between the address and the country is only possible if after the creation of the address I retrieve it with the find method.

```
$country = Country::find($input['country']);
$user = User::find($input['user']);

$address = Address::create($input);
$address = Address::find($address->id);   // Why?
$address->user()->associate($user);       // Always works
$address->country()->associate($country); // Now is working :)
$address->push();
```

Could you explain me why the association is behaving in that way, and if it's possible to fix it?

Then, I'm comparing the returned instances of the create method and the find method, and I noticed that some attributes are lost in the instance of the create method:

```
$createAddress = Address::create($input);
$findAddress = Address::find($address->id);
dd(['create' => $createAddress, 'find' => $findAddress]);
```

This is the output of dd():

```
array:2 [▼
  "create" => Address {#211 ▼
    #table: "addresses"
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #fillable: array:9 [▶]
    #hidden: array:3 [▶]
    #dates: array:3 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:12 [▼
      "alias" => "Home"
      "street" => "Home St."
      "number_external" => "123"
      "number_internal" => "456"
      "neighborhood" => "My beautiful neighborhood"
      "city" => "Cool City"
      "town" => "Cool Town"
      "state" => "Cool State"
      "zip_code" => "123456"
      "updated_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "created_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "id" => 43
    ]
    #original: array:12 [▼
      "alias" => "Home"
      "street" => "Home St."
      "number_external" => "123"
      "number_internal" => "456"
      "neighborhood" => "My beautiful neighborhood"
      "city" => "Cool City"
      "town" => "Cool Town"
      "state" => "Cool State"
      "zip_code" => "123456"
      "updated_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "created_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "id" => 43
    ]
    #relations: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: true
    #forceDeleting: false
  }
  "find" => Address {#232 ▼
    #table: "addresses"
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #fillable: array:9 [▶]
    #hidden: array:3 [▶]
    #dates: array:3 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:16 [▼
      "id" => "43"
      "alias" => "Home"
      "street" => "Home St."
      "number_external" => "123"
      "number_internal" => "456"
      "neighborhood" => "My beautiful neighborhood"
      "city" => "Cool City"
      "town" => "Cool Town"
      "state" => "Cool State"
      "country" => "0"
      "zip_code" => "123456"
      "is_legal_address" => "0"
      "user_id" => "0"
      "deleted_at" => null
      "created_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "updated_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
    ]
    #original: array:16 [▼
      "id" => "43"
      "alias" => "Home"
      "street" => "Home St."
      "number_external" => "123"
      "number_internal" => "456"
      "neighborhood" => "My beautiful neighborhood"
      "city" => "Cool City"
      "town" => "Cool Town"
      "state" => "Cool State"
      "country" => "0"
      "zip_code" => "123456"
      "is_legal_address" => "0"
      "user_id" => "0"
      "deleted_at" => null
      "created_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
      "updated_at" => "2015-12-09 11:10:14"
    ]
    #relations: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #forceDeleting: false
  }
]
```

MODELS:

```
class Address extends Model {
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
  }

  public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country', 'country');
  }
}

class Country extends Model {
  public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Address', 'country');
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Address', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you use the same column as your relationship. You have column `country` in your `addresses` table and you created relationship with name `country`.

You should change your relationship name or you should change your `country` column name to for example `country_id` (the second will be better if possible)

Comment: Hi Marcin, you are right, the problem is because the relationship and the column have the same name, so I did some tests and reached the same conclusion. 
Maybe is weird that I have not used the name convention for the country column, but you are right, I should change the name of the column.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But why the name of the column is not a problem after the find method, and only it is a problem after the create method?